# Tomcat 7 CPU usage on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, cpu, tomcat7

I deployed Java web application on Tomcat with Mongodb in Ubuntu 14.04. But Tomcat CPU usage increases suddenly to %100 after 5-6 hours. I couldn't find why. My htop logs like below.

[image: htop result]

[Digital Ocean Graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFCtX.png)

Comment: On my system tomcat only a tiny of system resource. It may not the tomcat issues.
You should check on you java code. Some `while` loop may use many system resources.

Comment: It happens also when i didn't send request to server. For example; I restarted Tomcat and I didn't send request but it happened again. And it happens suddenly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Tomcat 7 on Ubuntu 14.04. I believe this happens since the last Tomcat update USN-3177-2.

Someone had a similar issue with Debian 8: https://serverfault.com/q/827359

I solved this problem by disabling Port 8080 in server.xml.

Edit: The high CPU usage seems to start when someone accesses http://domain.com:8080. This also causes an error message in catalina.out:

```
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process
INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
```

Commenting out the connector with port 8080 in server.xml solved the problem for me.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer.

Comment: You mean this line                                                                            <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               redirectPort="8443" />                                                                           or this
 <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />.

Comment: Yes, I commented out this line. I only use port 8443 and don't need port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem. Here's a tweet I sent to @TheApacheTomcat asking if this was an known issue. https://twitter.com/jeromeleoterry/status/831865811962908672

They responded with a link to Bug 60578 https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60578

I was seeing the CPU spike when Nessus was scanning Tomcat servers on ports 8080 and 8009. I did a test in a QA environment with those connectors disabled, and the CPU load went up for a few seconds, then came back down.

i'm using Ubuntu 14.04 in EC2 using Tomcat 7.0.52.

Edit:
Looks like this is a known issue, and is resolved in newer versions of Tomcat.

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57544

Solution is to upgrade to Tomcat 7.0.60 or higher. Ubuntu 16.04 ships with Tomcat 7.0.68, so I'd recommend upgrading the OS if possible.

Comment: Do you know any document for upgrade Tomcat?